# How to link to a SalesForce tab with parameters

Tags: salesforce, visualforce, apex

This is a two part question.

Is it possible to create a hyperlink on a Visual Force page to open a SalesForce custom tab?

For example, a Visual Force page on the Opportunity Page Layout which has a "Open Report" link which opens / selects a tab, just as if the user had clicked on the tab.

The second question is: Is it possible to pass parameters (as query strings perhaps) to a Visual Force page which is contained on the tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this using `URLFOR()` though I haven't tried it with a tab before so [here's some documentation to help](http://salesforcesource.blogspot.com/2008/12/urlfor-function-finally-explained.html)

I do know that a custom tab can be referenced by name followed by `__tab` such as `My_Custom__tab`, or standard tabs by using `$Action` such as

> URLFOR($Action.Account.Tab, $ObjectType.Account)

And you can use the URLFOR to specify as many custom URL params as you want ([example here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/63234/2590)).